# context free grammar is unequivocal - how to show that

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

I have grammar like this:

```
{S->ɛ;S->aSb;S->aSc;S->SS}
```

how can I show it's unequivocal?

Comment: I can't see anything out there, I need a proof not algorith to solve this.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a proof of a conjecture in formal language theory, and has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: Hint: If you can construct an LR(1) parser, then the grammar is unambiguous.

Comment: @rici there is no tag suggesting that it's a programming question so it's not an off-topic I think.

Comment: SO is a site about programming. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: what does it mean to be unequivocal?

Comment: It means that You can't get one word in more than one way.